# Spring MVC release 4.2.6 seems does not inject mock service into the controller when testing controller method

Tags: spring, unit-testing, model-view-controller, controller, mockito

I really searched and followed the steps of creating a unit test class for spring MVC controller, however unit test is running with a green pass flag but the framework uses the original service class and it calls to the database. I mocked the class and used *`@InjectMocks`* together with *`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`*. Still when the test runs, the controller uses original service object rather than the mocked object. I really appreciate if somebody can help me in this regards.

Here is *`UserManager`*(*service* class), *`UserRegisterController`*(*controller*), *`TestUserRegisterController`* (*Test* class) classes with a picture of the *Eclipse* package structure

Service :

```
 @Service
    public class UserManager {

            protected Map<String, String> getAllCertificates() {

                Map<String, String> allCertificates = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //call to database
                return allCertificates;
            }




            protected User getUser(int userId) {
                //create session
                User user = session.get(User.class, userId);
                //close session
                return user;
            }

            }
```

Controller :

```
 @Controller
        public class UserRegisterController {

        @Autowired
        private UserManager manager;

        @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            //do some work

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getUser(@RequestParam(value="userId",   defaultValue="-1") String userId) {
            User user1;
            user1 = this.manager.getUser(Integer.parseInt(userId));
            if (user1 == null) {
                user1 = new User();
            }

            ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("User", "user1", user1);
            view.addObject("allCertificatesMap", this.manager.getAllCertificates());
            return view;
        }

        @ModelAttribute
        public void setModelAttribute(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("PageHeader", "lable.pageHeader");

        }

    }
```

Test class :

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration("test-spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class TestUserRegisterController {

        @Mock
        private UserManager userManager;

        @InjectMocks
        private UserRegisterController userRegisterController;

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            // Process mock annotations
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

            User user2 = new User();
            user2.setUserId(10006);
            user2.setUserName("Reza");
            user2.setHobby("Quadcopter");
            user2.setPhone("4032376295");

            when(this.userManager.getUser(10006)).thenReturn(user2);
            when(this.userManager.getAllCertificates()).thenReturn(new HashMap<String, String>());

            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

        }

        @Test
        public void getUser() {
            try {

                this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user.html").param("userId", "10006"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/User.jsp"))
                    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("User"))
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("allCertificatesMap"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

[Package hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI9U8.png)

Comment: There is no Spring 4.6.2 MVC release.

Comment: Hi, This is from read me file in the spring library that I downloaded. "Spring Framework version 4.2.6.RELEASE". You are right it does not have MVC in it.

Comment: It works as expected. Yo have 2 instances of your controller one with a mock and one regularly configured. Basically the way you are trying to inject a mock isn't going to work. Create a test context which creates a mock for the bean(s) you want to mock, give the bean the same name so it will override the original bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response. I simply copied the content of my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml into test-spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml and put the text context into my test directory as shown in Package hierarchy. Probably this is the source of issue. Since I am new to spring framework,  would you please provide a more detailed response that I can follow the steps. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please don't copy your context only create one that overrides the bean you want to mock. There are several questions (with answers) on stack overflow showing that.

Comment: @M.Deinum ,One way that I was able to solve this issue is to use   this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userRegisterController).build();  rather than this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();  when creating mockMvc.  This way the mock service was injected and not call to database anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to get the `@InjectMocks` and other annotations to work